# possible issue with jquery and mobile navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm customizing a wordpress template and running into an issue with the mobile version of the navigation. When there's a sub-menu under the main menu items, the main menu link won't work. I think it may be related to the way the data-toggle is working, but I'm not certain. Does anyone have any insight of what's causing the problem and how to fix it?

http://otpnet.staging.wpengine.com/

Comment: Please post your code, and not a link to your website.

Answer (score 0):

Dont really have much time to debug why its not working. But here is some js that will make it work.

```
jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    if( jQuery(this).next('.dropdown-menu').is(':visible') ) {
        jQuery(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut();
    } else {
        jQuery(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I put the code in a .js file and added it to the header: 

<script src="/wp-content/themes/otp2017-child/dropdown.js"></script>

So I either didn't add it correctly, or there's something else disabling the menu links. Any other ideas?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at dropdown.js:1

You need to include this after Jquery is being loaded.